# Leading Space when using .split

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have an assignmnt to modify a program from my text book. The program takes an input string from the user and then responds with how many words were enterd. My assignment is to change this to do a character count instead of a word count. I have this working fine, but I am getting a leading space in the array when I use .split to tokenize the characters can someone explain why?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
*
* @author Frank
*/
public class LetterCounting 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      // create HashMap to store String keys and Integer values
      Map< String, Integer > myMap = new HashMap< String, Integer >(); 

      createMap( myMap ); // create map based on user input
      displayMap( myMap ); // display map content
   } // end main

   // create map from user input
   private static void createMap( Map< String, Integer > map ) 
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ); // create scanner
      System.out.println( "Enter a string:" ); // prompt for user input
      String input = scanner.nextLine();

      // tokenize the input
      String letters = input.replaceAll("\\s", "");
      String[] tokens = letters.split( "" );

      // processing input text 
      for ( String token : tokens ) 
      {
         String word = token.toLowerCase(); // get lowercase word

         // if the map contains the word
         if ( map.containsKey( word ) ) // is word in map
         {
            int count = map.get( word ); // get current count
            map.put( word, count + 1 ); // increment count
         } // end if
         else 
            map.put( word, 1 ); // add new word with a count of 1 to map
      } // end for
   } // end method createMap

   // display map content
   private static void displayMap( Map< String, Integer > map ) 
   {      
      Set< String > keys = map.keySet(); // get keys

      // sort keys
      TreeSet< String > sortedKeys = new TreeSet< String >( keys );

      System.out.println( "\nMap contains:\nKey\t\tValue" );

      // generate output for each key in map
      for ( String key : sortedKeys )
         System.out.printf( "%-10s%10s\n", key, map.get( key ) );

      System.out.printf( 
         "\nsize: %d\nisEmpty: %b\n", map.size(), map.isEmpty() );
   } // end method displayMap
} // end class WordTypeCount
```

I have a screen capture of the dubug data from netbeans, but I do not have enough reputation to post it. If someone wants to see it let me know and I can send it to you.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Frank

Comment: You can use [`.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to get rid of leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Why don't you split on spaces to count the words: `String[] tokens = letters.split("\\s");` (without the `replaceAll` line)?

Comment: Baz - I can try .trim(), but after I use .replaceAll there are no spaces, but when I then use .split a leading space is put the array at index 0.

Comment: assylias - I need to count the characters, not the words. The program already counts words and my assignment is to modify the original program.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method and wirte a simple code as below?

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ); // create scanner
    System.out.println( "Enter a string:" ); // prompt for user input
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(inputString);
    System.out.println(inputString.length());
    String truncatedString = inputString.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(truncatedString);
    System.out.println(truncatedString.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

String.split() uses regular expressions for the splitting. You could use one of the splitXYZ() methods from the [StringUtils library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) instead, which works with Strings as separators and produces much more predictable results.